# Black corner on pictures

Tags: mirrorless, full-frame, 50mm

I noticed that all the pictures I have taken the other day have the top right corner that is black (see example below). There is various pictures with different aperture and exposure, all with the same problem but more or less marked but it doesn't look like it depends on the aperture nor exposure.

I have read the answers to this [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38256/what-can-cause-black-corners-in-an-image), but it doesn't cover my problem.

The picture were taken with a sony a7iii with the sony FE 1.8/50mm lens, without any lens hood. I tried to reproduce the problem back home when I noticed it (the camera was still in the same setup) but couldn't.

What causes this black top right corner? Could cold cause this? Is there a defect on the shutter?

[image: Montain with a black corner]

Comment: Did you take those photos with electronic shutter?

Comment: And do those "patches" appear with the same size and shape?

Comment: Where you standing outside under open sky? Or perhaps shooting through a window or from under a shelter of some kind?

Comment: @MichaelC open sky outside, various locations.

Comment: @RomeoNinov The shape is always the same but on some shots it can be bigger or smaller. I also noticed on one shot I have this on two corners (top right and bottom right). And it was shot with mechanical shutter.

Comment: It could be a shutter malfunction - these often show up with short exposure times first. You could easily check by shooting into a bright light and then slowly going for shorter exposure times.

Comment: You weren't wearing a hat were you?

Comment: @J.Hirsch, good thinking, but no, I was not wearing a hat.

Comment: @Puck I'm sorry to say then I'm out of ideas really. Given the nature of being in the upper right corner (which is the lower left on the frame), there's not a lot of things that pop up in that general area. Since it wasn't reproducible ... You know, were you in a building taking photos? Could that have been part of a roof line ?

Comment: And if you want to PM a link to several photos that show the same artifact I wouldn't mind a distraction right now to see if they match or if they're different.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clarifications from OP for me this look like (random) problem with shutter. Will be good if OP can check in EXIF if this happen when taking fotos with mechanical shutter.

And it is wise to contact authorized service center where they can diagnose better the problem

Answer (score 1):

So an intermittent shutter isn't going to be easily diagnosed. If the camera was particularly cold the mechanism that moves the blades out of the way may be slower. However what you're showing is a significant loss of exposure.

It honestly looks as if it's part of a lens hood or something stuck inside of the camera. I understand you said there was no lens hood, so that's ruled out. That is, however, the cleanest answer. And if something was stuck in the camera (did you remove a lens?) it could do that too.

I've accidentally made these while holding my hand up to shade the light from my eyes, or when wearing a hat with a short lens- the hat covers portions in the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an incorrectly oriented lens hood. Lens hoods for zoom lenses are leaf -like, with cutouts which are designed to avoid shading the corners. The most important bits of the petal should be top and bottom, if the hood is rotated it might be the corners of the image are being blocked by the hood.

Comment: It is mentionned in the question that no lens hood is used and the linked question already mention it.